# What is the equation for the walls of a 3D cylinder?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

If for example I have the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ in the $x$-$y$ plane, and I want to extend it upwards into the $z$ dimension, how would I write the equation for the circular walls in terms of $z$?

Answer (score 1):

The same equation will work, as for given $x_0$ and $y_0$ on the circle, for any $z$, at the vertical of  $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_0,y_0,z)$ will be on the wall, as in the figure from  [Quadric Surfaces](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces.aspx):

[image]

If you really miss the $z$, try $x^2 + y^2 + 0\times z = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you wrote is for an entire cylinder of unspecified height.But to specify where it starts and ends,

the (x,y,z) surface (cylinder ) parametrization is

$$ (x = 2 \cos u, y=2 \sin u, z=v ),( 0< u< 2 \pi), ( hmin < v < hmax) $$

Where the height is between two limits.

Useful for extruded /prismatic surfaces.